# c# setup file for windows application

Tags: c#

Greetings!

I am creating setup file for my project.i have some folders in my project,for eaxmple say test folder. how to include this folders while creating a setup. coz now its not coming when i create a setup. please give me a solution.

thank you

regards
jennie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propobly need to set

```
BuildAction=Content
```

and

```
Copy to output directory = Copy always
```

on files in those folders. After that should be included in deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with Visual Studio ,making setup's but now im using **Smart Setup Maker** or **Install Shield** .There you can manage some great things Including other Setup Files if you're application need's other Software's .Also using Install Shield you can provide some triggers like user should have .NET 3.5 installed etc.

Comment: Good recommendation, but bad english... (also, I'd use WiX personally, but same difference)

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham If you got the message ,say thanks or let me know if you need something else .

Comment: If you clean up your answer, I think it's a decent one, so I'll up-vote it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add files/folders that are not a part of your project output, you can go to File System inside the setup project, select Application Folder from the left and drag and drop the required folder/files in the right, alternatively you can right click and select Add->Folder/File from the menu.